# OAuth2 HTTPRequest CORS Policy

Tags: javascript

I am authenticating against Strava API with the OAuth2 Authorization Code Grant Flow. In a first step I need to retrieve the Access Code from the Strava EndPoint. I am in development mode.

I have tried the following code:

```
//unsure about redirect_uri, localhost and 127.0.0.1 are white-listed
var url = "https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize";
var params ="client_id=*****&redirect_uri=127.0.0.1&response_type=code&scope=activity:write";
var request_url = url +"?"+ params;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', request_url, true);

request.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
    alert(http.responseText);
}
}
request.send(null);
```

This runs into a CORS error, where the request has been blocked because no "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is present on the requested resource. So I need to add a header.. So I have done the following as suggested in response to another question, but I still get the same error.

```
request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header, not a *request* header. The owner of `www.strava.com` would need to apply it.

More importantly, the OAuth flow requires that the user interacts with the webpage hosted by the OAuth authorize endpoint, so you can't use Ajax to load it, you need to redirect the main browser view to it (this renders CORS irrelevant for this part of the process).

See [the documentation](https://developers.strava.com/docs/authentication/) which says:

> **Redirect** the user to `GET https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize`.

(My emphasis).

Once the user is viewing that page in the browser, they'll get a prompt asking them if they want to give your website access to their account (after a prompt for them to log in if they haven't already).

[This guide to OAuth](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) might make things clearer.

Comment: I did not know about the response/ request header difference, so thank you. What I understood is that this OAuth2 grant type requires 3 HTTPRequests to be made, the first of them being a GET request to the address you mention. This is how I have seen it done.. You should indeed send the user to the address with the correct parameters in request. I will try to use POSTMAN for this, as it circumvenes the CORS policy issues..

Comment: @NielsVanwingh — You can't make your users use postman. You need to have them visit the page in their browser. Redirect them to it.